# EF Core - Invalid attempt to call CheckDataIsReady when reader is closed (OutOfMemory)

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, out-of-memory, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I have a table **dbo.Cache** in SQL server, with two Columns:

- Key : varchar(50)
- Value : nvarchar(max)

I am planning to store large strings in Value column (>30mb) and query them in multiple threads.

So the problem that when I do more then 9 queries in parallel, it starts throwing exception `System.InvalidOperationException : Invalid attempt to call CheckDataIsReady when reader is closed`:

```
[Fact]
public void TestMemory()
{
    const string key = "myKey1";
    //re-creating record with Value = large 30mb string
    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var existingRecord = db.CachedValues.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Key == key);
        if (existingRecord!=null)
        {
            db.Remove(existingRecord);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        var myHugeString = new string('*',30*1024*1024);
        db.CachedValues.Add(new CachedValue() {Key = key, Value = myHugeString});
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    //Try to load this record in parallel threads, creating new dbContext
    const int threads = 10;
    Parallel.For(1, threads, new ParallelOptions(){MaxDegreeOfParallelism = threads}, (i) =>
    {
        using (var db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var entity = db.CachedValues.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Key == key);
        }
    });
}
```

Tried to execute `GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();` before/after each db read - didn't not help

Tried to mimic this behavior on the lower level directly reading data through `sqlDataReader.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess)` - it throws `OutOfMemoryException`

Comment: Have you tried using MultipleActiveResultSets=True in your connection string?

Comment: Yes, I did - still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

So after investigation I figured out that it's just an OutOfMemory problem because after 8th parallel request allocating 30mb*2 (since it's unicode char) amount of memory allocated by .Net actually goes over 1.2GB in my app, which is enough for my workstation .net runtime to start chocking on lack of memory (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals#ephemeral-generations-and-segments).

So having that said there is not much else I can come up with just on retrying the read (mem allocate) operation until it succeed with forcing GC to collect in the catch block.

```
Retry.Action(() =>
{
    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var entity = db.CachedValues.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Key == key);
    }
}).OnException((OutOfMemoryException exception) =>
{
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
    return true;

})
.OnException((InvalidOperationException exception) =>
{
    if (exception.Message != "Invalid attempt to call CheckDataIsReady when reader is closed.")
    {
        return false;
    }

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
    return true;

})
.Run();
```

Please let me know if you know some better solution for that

Comment: Mhm... damn... actually not a good way to go. Maybe open an issue at the NHibernate github and ask for advice.

I feel like the OutOfMemoryException should be thrown out of the NHibernate framework instead of the InvalidOperationException.

But in general OOM's are very hard to handle

Comment: can't agree more, throwing some first consequent exception instead the root OutOfMemory - is definitely a bug/flaw. Feel free to create a ticket for Entity Framework Core repository